# Convert array of bytes in to array of matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array of arrays and I need to convert this array in array of matrices, each one represented as 25x25.

Array of arrays:

```
[[1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 ...
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

I hope to get the following

```
[
 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]] (25x25)

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]] (25x25)

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] ... [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]] (25x25)
  ]
```

Comment: what's the shape of input array?

Comment: (n, 8), n depends of a input stream of int16 that I convert to bytes.

Comment: I have to convert to one array(1,n) of matrices(25,25) of arrays(1,8)